# WinForms screenshots with multiple displays

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms application, and I need to take a screenshot of a particular control. Normally this would be simple (DrawToBitmap) but the control I need to screenshot doesn't support this (ChromiumWebBrowser/CefSharp). As such I've been using the following code to take a screenshot:

```
Rectangle bounds = browser.Bounds;
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        int borderWidth = (this.Width - this.ClientSize.Width) / 2;
        int titleBarHeight = this.Height - this.ClientSize.Height + toolStrip1.Height - borderWidth;
        g.CopyFromScreen(browser.Left, this.Top + browser.Top + titleBarHeight, 0, 0, bounds.Size);  
    }
}
```

This finds the position of the control I need to screenshot, and takes a screenshot of just that control. This works fine, however if I move the application to another monitor, the screenshot is taken of the correct area but on the main monitor instead.

Is there a simpler way of approaching this?

Comment: You are simply passing wrong arguments to CopyFromScreen(), browser.Left/Top are *relative* coordinates, not screen coordinates.  Use browser.PointToScreen() to fix.

Comment: @HansPassant That was far simpler than I thought it would be! I was expecting to spend several hours fixing this. Thanks!